# Calculate the curvature of torus using the shape operator and check the Gauss-Bonnet theorem $\iint_{S} K(\vec{r}) d S=4 \pi(1-g)$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am trying to check the Gauss-Bonnet theorem which says $$\iint_{S} K(\vec{r}) d S=4 \pi(1-g),$$ where $g$ is the genus. For a torus, $g=1$.

I am given a hint that I can get $K$ from the shape operator $$A(\vec{X})=-\left(X^{1} \hat{N}_{1}+X^{2} \hat{N}_{2}\right)$$
$$K\left(\vec{r}\left(u_{1}, u_{2}\right)\right)=\operatorname{det}\left([A]_{B}^{B}\right)$$ while $B$ is the basis for a tangent plane.

I think my main problem is to derive the curvature for the torus.

Comment: Your hint is a fine one, but you can also parameterize the torus and calculate the coefficients of the first fundamental form, and noting that for a torus $F=0$ thus $K= -1/\sqrt{EG}$.

Comment: @Kevin we should use the only the seond dunamental form, do you have any idea how do I use it?

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterization of the torus can be written as follows:
$$T(\varphi, \theta) = ((R+r\cos(\theta))\cos(\varphi), (R+r\cos(\theta))\sin(\varphi), r\sin(\theta))$$

Now consider a parameterization $T:U\rightarrow M$ for a regular surface $M$.Denote by $n$ the unit normal to the surface. I was given the following defition for the matrix $B$ that defines the second fundamental form:

$$\mathcal{S}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    T''_{\varphi \varphi}\cdot n & T''_{\varphi \theta}\cdot n \\
    T''_{\theta \varphi}\cdot n & T''_{\theta \theta}\cdot n \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Also, given the following definition that defines the (matix version of the) Riemannian metric:
$$g=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    T'_\varphi\cdot T'_\varphi & T'_\varphi\cdot r'_\theta \\
    r'_\theta \cdot r'_\varphi & r'_\theta\cdot r'_\theta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

These should be straight forward for you to calculate given the parameterization above.

*Edit*

Let $K$ be the Gauss curvature.  You would like to compute $\iint_{T} K \: dA$.  Remember that

$$ dA = \sqrt{EG-F^2} d \varphi \: d \theta =  (R+r\cos \theta)\: d\varphi \:d\theta $$

Since you have already shown $$K = \frac{r\cos \theta}{r(R+r\cos \theta)}$$,

$$\iint_{T} K dA = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r\cos \theta}{r(R+r\cos \theta)} \cdot r (R+r\cos \theta) \:d \varphi \: d\theta=\iint_{T} r\cos \theta \:d \varphi d\theta $$

Hopefully you can take this forward.

Comment: How there is variable $r$ in the parametrization?

Comment: $R$ is the radius of the whole 'donut', $r$ is the radius of the 'cylinder' if you follow me...

Comment: Ok , my bad now I understand, just last question, by integrating the surface integral of $K$ what should be the limit of $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: I found  $K= \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r(R + a \cos(\theta)}$ how should I evaluate my integral now? what is my $ds$?

Comment: @Sagigever Excellent! Please see my edit above.